# MySQL Count multiple columns at once or separate transactions

Tags: mysql

I have a daily cron that counts the number of non-null and non-empty string rows for a specific column, such as:

```
SELECT count(first_name) FROM users WHERE first_name IS NOT NULL and first_name IS != ''
SELECT count(last_name) FROM users WHERE last_name IS NOT NULL and first_name IS != ''
```

Would the performance be improved if I did this in one MySQL call?

Comment: One hit of the db is better than 2.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT first_name), COUNT(DISTINCT last_name) FROM users`  ?

Comment: @Alex: I guess that would include cases where xxx_name = ''

Comment: @EricJ. yes, but in 99% of cases I guess it is acceptable. If not - you can add `WHERE`

Comment: I suppose he has that check in his current WHERE explicitly for a reason.  How would you add it to WHERE and get the count exactly right in all cases, e.g. for user '', 'Jones' and 'Tom', ''?

Comment: @Alex Add an answer. Yours is better than the others.

Comment: @Michael I can't fully agree with that. Count distinct will not exclude blank values. Adding a where to exclude blanks will not be that easy.

Comment: This is actually more difficult than it looks isn't it.

Comment: Perhaps the most obvious solution of all should have been suggested, a union, I mean like: select 'first_name', count(first_name) from users where first_name IS NOT NULL and first_name != '' union select 'last_name', count(last_name) from users where last_name IS NOT NULL and last_name != ''

Answer (score 0):

Use a CASE condition for 1 query

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN first_name IS NOT NULL and first_name != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN last_name IS NOT NULL and last_name != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM users
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is faster than running 2 queries

Comment: I think the select count(distinct ... solution in the question comments would outperform this answer to be honest.

Comment: It`s hard to see how 2 queries can be faster than 1 especially for a simple condition.Hitting the db twice is enough overhead already

Comment: @Mihai I agree, I'd be surprised too. The latency of 2 round trips alone means 1 query will often outperform 2. Yours is quite a mouthful though, I have absolutely no idea what an SQL server would do generally to optimise that. I think Shadow might be right for some cases of large amounts of rows in the DB.

Comment: @Michael As a general "rule" 1 trip is better.I agree that for a complicated query with billions of rows,more queries would be faster,especially if there are concurrency issues.I`m also curious for an explain of both situations @Hank

Comment: @Mihai you can combine the 2 separate selects with a union and there are no 2 roundtrips. Where conditions may take advantage of indexes (selectivity will be a question, though), your solution cannot use indexes, full table scan only.

Comment: I'm not sure any of the suggestions could usefully utilise an index to be fair. An index could probably only be used to eliminate nulls and empties before proceeding as far as I can see, and this is an assumption, but I imagine a data set with a significant amount of nulls and empties wouldn't be typical.

Comment: @Michael I`m starting to think this is a case where the Premature optimization is the root of all evil might apply.

Comment: @Mihai Hah! You are so right, look how much attention, bickering and controversy this fairly unimportant question has attracted. Although the OP has done an excellent job of concurrent fitness evaluation by forking a bunch of stackoverflow users to get the job done.

Comment: @Mihai I'm trying to optimize previous code written by another developer, and he chose to use multiple queries instead of one. Our table has around 45 million rows, so I'm looking for any possible performance boost. And I may have only shown two columns, but we do separate queries for about 10 different columns.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this query is enough:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT first_name), COUNT(DISTINCT last_name) FROM users
```

As other developers pointed this `COUNT` will count even `''` empty value.

IMHO that is acceptable. If not you can:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT first_name)-1, COUNT(DISTINCT last_name)-1 FROM users
```

It is not exactly what you need, but if you are sure that you have those empty value that will work :

If you want clear query that return correct `COUNT` you should better use @Mihai query:

```
   SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN first_name IS NOT NULL and first_name != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
   SUM(CASE WHEN last_name IS NOT NULL and last_name != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM user
```

But this one can hit the performance a lot on big numbers of records.

Comment: Count distinct includes blanks. You can't simply do a -1 without checking if there are blank values. The 3rd has alredy been suggested.

Comment: @Shadow I already saw your comment. Thank you for your opinion.